# Executable path /usr/bin/gnome internal error

Tags: gnome, executable, error-handling

I cant open ubuntu software and everytime it crashes, I get an internal error:

```
Executable path /usr/bin/gnome-software
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: same error (see comments below the question): http://askubuntu.com/questions/857561/ubuntu-16-04-lts-gnome-software-crash Bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1552074 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1647187

Comment: Thanks, I couldnt find the exact error because it didnt open again but i did: 'sudo apt-get update', 'sudo apt-get upgrade' and the error was fixed.

Comment: cool! make it an answer and accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I typed in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I did this because the error didn't appear again. I thought i may try this and it worked.